# Excel Analytics : Replace values in the 2nd column

Tags: excel, function, analytics

Image has been attached in the below link :
[Excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQQuS.png)

As you can see, there are four columns with numbers in the image, the first column has numbers in sequence, and the 2nd column has numbers from 1-8 that are non-zero.Now, the 4th column is the filtered 1st column, and the 5th column has no non-zero numbers.  
 What I want is for the numbers from the 5th column to paste by replacing zeros in the 2nd column for the corresponding ColA values. The 1st column again is a sequence of numbers and the numbers from 4th column are further down in the 1st column.
 I hope this makes sense. Look at first eight rows for clarification. Please tell me a function that will do the job for me. I really need something like that.

Much appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: me neither. Input and desired output would help

Comment: You could achieve this with [Advanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple cross poster different forums
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/907072-excel-analytics-replace-values-2nd-column.html